# How to add a new string at the end of line after searching a string in that line in a file in Unix

Tags: shell, unix, autosys

I have a file which is an extract of jil codes of all autosys jobs in our server.

**Sample jil code:**

```
permission:gx,wx  
date_conditions:yes  
days_of_week:all  
start_times:"05:00"  
condition: notrunning(appDev#box#ProductLoad)
```

We want add a new dependency condition for all the jobs in the server.
So we would need to add a new string at the end of line(line which have dependency conditions) as shown below and then reload the jobs in to the server:

```
condition: notrunning(appDev#box#ProductLoad) & s(new_job_dependency)
```

We have 10000+ jobs(and 100K lines of data in the file) in the server, and reading line by line and doing the changes is not possible.
We have to search for the string 'condition:' at the begining of the line and then add new string 'new_job_dependency' at the end of the same line.

Could some one please suggest a way to achieve this?

Comment: S.O. is NOT a free coding service, you're expected to have shown a minimal effort to have solved your problem. 10000+ jobs? Maybe you better hire a consultant. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

How about replacing all of them with some perl magic

```
perl -i -pe  's#^condition: (.*)$#condition: $1 & s(new_job_dependency)#g' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed` can help you:

```
$ sed '/^condition:/s/$/ \& s(new_job_dependency)/' file
permission:gx,wx  
date_conditions:yes  
days_of_week:all  
start_times:"05:00"  
condition: notrunning(appDev#box#ProductLoad) & s(new_job_dependency)
```

You can add `-i.bak` if you want the file to be updated on the fly and a `.bak` backup file to be created.

```
sed -i.bak '/^condition:/s/$/ \& s(new_job_dependency)/' file
```

To make it apply into an specific directory, do:

```
sed -i.bak '/^condition:/s/$/ \& s(new_job_dependency)/' your_dir/files*
```